# How to implement a Custom or Flutter Loading Indicator

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have wrapped the body of the code below using `GestureDetector`, thus enabling me to use `onVerticalDragEnd` method available in the widget. When the app detects a Vertical Drag the `_onRefreshing` function is called, where it updates the Text widget after a delay of 2 seconds.

I want to include a Loading indicator while the `_onRefreshing` function is running.

How do I implement this task in Flutter?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  dynamic balanceAvailable = 0;

  void _onRefreshing(DragEndDetails details) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy > 0) {
      setState(() {
        balanceAvailable = 1000;
      });
      print('newbalance : $balanceAvailable');
      print(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GestureDetector(
          onVerticalDragEnd: _onRefreshing,
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("Button 1"),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 100.0),
                Text('$balanceAvailable'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a CircularProgressIndicator inside a showdialog in your _onRefreshing method.
After the 2 seconds delay, you can remove it with Navigator.pop();
Maybe like this:

```
void _onRefreshing(DragEndDetails details) async {
        showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
          );

        });
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy > 0) {
      setState(() {
        balanceAvailable = 1000;
      });
      print('newbalance : $balanceAvailable');
      print(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy);
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you can share a sample code

Comment: I got the following error lib/main.dart:160:19: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
     Navigator.pop();
                  ^
../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2570:15: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static void pop<T extends Object?>(BuildContext context, [ T? result ]) {

Comment: 'Navigator.pop(context);' sorry.

Comment: I got the following after the above correction: [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: No MaterialLocalizations found.
MyApp widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.
The material library uses Localizations to generate messages, labels, and abbreviations.
To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a MaterialApp at the root of your application to include them automatically, or add a Localization widget with a MaterialLocalizations delegate.

Comment: contiue: The specific widget that could not find a MaterialLocalizations ancestor was:
  MyApp
The ancestors of this widget were:
  [root] #0      debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:72:7)
#1      debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:92:4)
#2      showDialog (package:flutter/src/material/dialog.dart:980:10)
#3      _MyAppState._onRefreshing (package:plaid_flutter_app/main.dart:138:5)
#4      DragGestureRecognizer._checkEnd.<anonymous closure> (package:flut<…>